# How to check for common values between two Linked Lists?

Tags: singly-linked-list

```
public void setIntersection(LinkList list1, LinkList list2) {
    LinkList list4 = new LinkList();
    Node a = list1.head;
    Node b = list2.head;
    while (a != null && b != null) {
        if (a.value < b.value) {
            a = a.next;
        } else if (a.value > b.value) {
            b = b.next;
        } else if (a.value == b.value){
            list4.insert(a.value);
            a = a.next;
            b = b.next;
        }
    }
    list4.printList();
}
```

I want to find out the common values appearing in List 1 and List 2 and save the entries in List4. Although this seems straight forward, I still feel my code is too long and wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Is this homework? Please use the tag if so.

Comment: No this is not. This was an interview question and I was only trying to see if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct LinkList
{
     int data;
     struct LinkList *next;
}*list1,*list2,*list4;

public void setIntersection(LinkList *list1, LinkList *list2) 
{
    LinkList *temp, *temp1, *temp2, *node;
    for(temp1 = list1;temp1!=null;temp1=temp1->next)
    {
     enter code here    for(temp2 = list2;temp2!=null;temp2=temp2->next)
         {
              if(temp1->data == temp2->data)
              {
                  node = (struct LinkList *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkList));
                  node->next = null;
                  if(list4==null)
                  {
                        list4 = node;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        for(temp = list4;temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next);
                        temp->next = node;
                  }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this should work. But I feel the time complexity for this problem is still the same as my solution. Is there a better way to get to the solution? Correct me if im wrong.